# Openshot crash importing picture

Tags: fedora

It is about some days that I like to use Openshot like before in Fedora to make animation from pictures but just after importing pictures to the app it crash.
I could not find any clue to fix it.
I tested over the other Linux and got the same results. It means no issue with Linux nor with Openshot.

Answer (score 0):

After long headache I figure out why it was crashed, it was related to my folder name that I like to import my files from that. it had "%" on its name, when I rename my folder and chose simple name it fixed.